# Multiple inserts with Lombok Builder

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, lombok

is there a way to add multiple **Questions** and **Answers** in my Builder.Build() code?
I want to let user create many questions with answers, I want it to create dynamic. Is there a way to do it?

This is my Questions Table

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Questions {

    @Id

    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.AUTO
    )
    private Long questionId;
    private String Question;
    private String Answer;

    @OneToOne(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            optional = false


    )
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "quizz_name",
            referencedColumnName = "quizName"
    )
    private Quiz quiz;
}
```

This is my Test Class

```
    @Test
    public void addQuestion(){




        Quiz quiz =
                Quiz.builder()
                        .quizName("Words in German")
                        .build();



        Questions questions =
                Questions.builder()
                        .Question("Run")
                        .Answer("Lauf")
                        .quiz(quiz)
                        .build();
        
        questionRepository.save(questions);


    }
```

If I add Question and Answer once again, only "**Money**" and "**Geld**" will be added into database.

```
 @Test
    public void addQuestion(){




        Quiz quiz =
                Quiz.builder()
                        .quizName("Words in German")
                        .build();



        Questions questions =
                Questions.builder()
                        .Question("Run")
                        .Answer("Lauf")
                        .Question("Money")
                        .Answer("Geld")
                        .quiz(quiz)
                        .build();

        questionRepository.save(questions);


    }
```

Comment: Try adding a method that returns a question and is called everytime you need a new question. For instance `Question question1=newQuestion("Run", "Lieben");`.  In the newQuestion method the builder will generate a new question instance and the variable will be saved and then returned.

Comment: What about using loop and (possibly) `CrudRepository#saveAll`?

Answer (score 1):

In order to add more than one `Answer` and `Question`, your `Questions` class should be able to hold those values.

You have to change your `Questions` class like this,

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@Entity
public class Questions {

    @Id

    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.AUTO
    )
    private Long questionId;

    @ElementCollection
    @Singular 
    private List<String> questions;

    @ElementCollection
    @Singular 
    private List<String> answers;

    @OneToOne(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            optional = false
    )
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "quizz_name",
            referencedColumnName = "quizName"
    )
    private Quiz quiz;
}
```

Then you can build `Questions` like this,

```
Questions questions = Questions.builder()
                        .question("Question 1")
                        .answer("Answer 1")
                        .question("Question 2")
                        .answer("Answer 2")
                        .quiz(quiz)
                        .build();
```

Note that `@Singular` is `Lombock` annotation which simplify adding collection type attribute. For more info [here.](https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-builder-singular)

`@ElementCollection` is a `hibernate` annotation which use to persists non-entity simple types. For more info [here.](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-tagging)

Comment: When i paste your code, "@Data" and "@Builder" is a bug, after refactoring, it still doesn't work. Thank you anyway

Comment: Still doesn't work. In Question class "Can't singularize this name: "answer"; please specify the singular explicitly (i.e. @Singular("sheep"))", "Class 'Questions' should have [public, protected] no-arg constructor". In Test class "Cannot resolve method 'builder' in 'Questions'". There is still problem with "@Builder"

Comment: Check the answe again. Parameter name chaged to `questions` and `answers`. Do you use any IDE like InteliJ?

Comment: Yes, i refactored everything i could. Yep, i use intellij.

Comment: I have renamed `Question` to `questions` and  `Answer` to `answers`. Also their data type was changed from `String` to `List<String>`.

Answer (score 0):

this is simple a way. 
Add a list.

```
Quiz quiz =
            Quiz.builder()
                    .quizName("Words in German")
                    .build();
List<Questions> questions = new ArrayList<>();
questions.add(Questions.builder().Question("Run").Answer("Lauf").build());
questions.add(Questions.builder().Question("Money").Answer("Geld").build());
questions.stream()
         .foreach(e->{
            questionRepository.save(e);
          });
```